# Solr + schema.xml creating custom FieldType Object

Tags: indexing, solr, schema, fieldtype

This is only an example, but it will Help me to get further

I have an Object "person" with Fields [Age,Name]

My schema.xml

```
<field name="age" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

everything is ok, but I want to **add +1 more Field "relation"** (or parents,children etc.)
Person[age,name,relation] -> Relation has also [age,name]

how can i, insert a FieldType Relation to my schema.xml ?

```
<field name="age" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<field name="relation" type="???" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

I want to add an Field, which takes all existing Fields like above

```
<field name="field1" type="string">
<field name="field2" type="string">
<field name="field3" type="string">
<field name="field4" type="field1,field2,field3">
```

Answer (score 1):

Solr doesn't really support what you want, so you'd probably either index it with a multivalued field that contains ids that point to the other documents, such as (any reason why the age field is a string and not an int?):

```
<field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<field name="age" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<field name="relation" type="int" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="false" />
```

.. and then query all documents with a given relation when displaying a document (making two queries to Solr).

You can [also use nested child documents](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-NestedChildDocuments), but it requires a bit more handling (since everything is contained in one document, you'll have to update everything together).

Comment: it was a mistake, age should be int. The idea to store the Id's is very clever. I wil try it.
And i saw the nested child documents before, but they dont explain what kind of fieldType they use

Comment: They use the same field type as the rest of your index. They're indexed in the same core as documents as the "parent" documents, but are "joined" as a block when you query and index. If you look at the example linked above, you can see that their ids are distinct for each document or sub document.

Answer (score 0):

Solr prefers everything to be in denormalized way. Multi value is in that direction. But as @MatsLindh said, it involves 2 queries, because most of the times the child entities would be more than just a single field(arrays of strings v/s array of entities).

(Parent and child in your case is Person and "relation")
Nested child documents, is more of object relation, just like how we have in other frameworks. You have parent documents, you have child documents, and solr maintains the relationship and we should have a field which identies parent from child. The good part about this is

1. You can get parent document with child field matching
2. All child documents for a parent field matching
3. Finally only one query

Nested stuff, is recent addition. We are using lucid works to interact with solr. They suggested not to use nested documents, so we ended up with multivalue. But if allowed at your infrastructure, and solr framework itself having the feature, i think there is no wrong in using it.